# How to create append method in Singly Linkedlist in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

Our task is to create a class that implements an append method in a singly linked list, my problem is that I cannot visualize how I'm going to connect the two linked lists.

```
public class LinkedList implements Singly {

    private Node head;

    private class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

         // Append method
        public void append(LinkedList list) {
          head.next = list.head;
        }
    }
```

Here's my code, i vizualize it as, the head of the passed linklist will going to connect to the head.next

Comment: What if `head.next` isn't null and is already pointing to the next node of the first list? Can you find a node in the list where `next` is `null`?

Comment: I recommend you have `public void append (LinkedList list)` in `class LinkedList`, not in `class Node`.  Since your `LinkedList` class has no `Node tail`, walk through the `this` list until you find the last node.  Then join them.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I am not allowed to post images yet (my reputation is too low). Thus, they are just links.

Let's assume you have two lists, `List1 = [0,1,2]` and `List2 = ['A', 'B']`. 
This would look something like that:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAvb5.png)

You want to end up with the following result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5REY.png)

To achieve this, you have to find the node of `List1` with `node.next == null`. 
Then, you can assign `node.next = List2.head`.